# Axios Post Request return Error 400 when that same data and URL works with Postman (Django DRF React.js)

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm creating an application that uses Django as the backend, and React.js as the front end. I'm using DRF for the api calls from React.js to Django, but am facing an issue with sending a post request. When I send a post request with the relevant data in JSON format using axios in React.js , it returns an error code of 400. However, when I copy that same JSON data and use it to send a post request in Postman, there was no error and the code was 201 (created). I'm not too sure why there is this issue, and I have already set the necessary settings in the Django settings.py to ensure that permission is granted (for testing purposes I just set it to 'allow all'). I managed to print out the error message behind the failed post request, but I do not really understand what the error message is talking about. If there is any other way to print out more error messages to sort of let me know where to start, please let me know, thanks! Any help is appreciated!

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

the error message in console after 400 error code

```
{message: "Request failed with status code 400", name: "Error", description: undefined, number: 
 undefined, fileName: undefined, …}
 message: "Request failed with status code 400"
 name: "Error"
 description: undefined
 number: undefined
 fileName: undefined
 lineNumber: undefined
 columnNumber: undefined
 stack: "Error: Request failed with status code 400↵    at createError 
 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:117160:15)↵    at settle 
 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:117381:12)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad 
 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:116635:7)"
 config:
 url: "http://localhost:8000/api/customer-information/"
 method: "post"
 data: "{"customer_name":"test", 
 "telephone_number":"123","incorporation_country":"A","address":"B", 
 "fax_number":"123","control":"d"}"
 headers:
 Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
 Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 __proto__: Object
 transformRequest: [ƒ]
 transformResponse: [ƒ]
 timeout: 0
 adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
 xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
 xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
 maxContentLength: -1
 validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus(status)
 __proto__: Object
 code: undefined
 __proto__: Object
```

axios request

```
    onSubmit = (data) => {
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(data);
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/customer-information/', data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.toJSON());
            })
    };
```